# Unix command to create new output file by combining 2 files based on condition

Tags: linux, unix, join, awk, sed

I have 2 files. Basically i want to match the column names from File 1           with the column name listed in the File 2. The resulting output File should have   data for the column that matches with File 2 and Null value for the remaining     column name in File 2.

**Example**:

file1

```
Name|Phone_Number|Location|Email
Jim|032131|xyz|xyz@qqq.com
Tim|037903|zzz|zzz@qqq.com
Pim|039141|xxz|xxz@qqq.com
```

File2

```
Location
Name
Age
```

Based on these 2 files, I want to create new file which has data in the   below format:

Output:

```
Location|Name|Age
    xyz|Jim|Null
    zzz|Tim|Null
    xxz|Pim|Null
```

Is there a way to get this result using `join`, `awk` or `sed`. I tried with join but couldnt get it working.

Comment: you're correct that `join` can't do this, but StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show an attempt to solve your problem. I would recommend `awk`, but any language at that level or higher will work well. Not downvoting (yet ;-) ) as your Q is otherwise well documented. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==FNR { names[++numNames] = $0; next }
FNR==1 {
    for (nameNr=1;nameNr<=numNames;nameNr++) {
        name = names[nameNr]
        printf "%s%s", name, (nameNr<numNames?OFS:ORS)
    }
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        name2fldNr[$i] = i
    }
    next
}
{
    for (nameNr=1;nameNr<=numNames;nameNr++) {
        name = names[nameNr]
        fldNr = name2fldNr[name]
        printf "%s%s", (fldNr?$fldNr:"Null"), (nameNr<numNames?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
Location|Name|Age
xyz|Jim|Null
zzz|Tim|Null
xxz|Pim|Null
```

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks a lot Morton. Found it useful

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using csvcut, which is part of CSVKit (https://csvkit.readthedocs.org), along the lines of the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
HEADERS=File2
PSV=File1

headers=$(tr '\n' , < "$HEADERS" | sed 's/,$//' )

awk '-F|' '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS}
    NR==1 {print $0,"Age"; next}
    {print $0, "Null"}' "$PSV" ) |\
  csvcut "-d|" -c "$headers"
```

I realize this may not be entirely satisfactory, but csvcut doesn't currently have options to handle missing columns or translate missing data to a specified value.

Comment: `'-F|'`? `-F'|'` would be the more normal way to write it. The backslash after the `|` is doing nothing, get rid of it. You're missing a `"` after `$PSV`. Don't use all upper case for non-exported variables.